# Corda confidential identities where does it gets stored in H2

Tags: corda

Corda confidential identities are generated using Well-Known identities, where does it gets stored? I have check table NODE_IDENTITIES and NODE_NAMED_IDENTITIES, what is difference between these 2 tables?

If confidential identities stored inside the NODE_IDENTITES then How does corda maps it with well known identity?

Answer (score 0):

`NODE_IDENTITIES` is a mapping of every public-key hash (well-known or anonymous) to a `PartyAndCertificate` object.

`NODE_NAMED_IDENTITIES` is a mapping of node names to public-key hashes.

Confidential identities are mapped to well-known identities using the certificate part of the `PartyAndCertificate` object. Each certificate has a `CertRole` extension. The extension for confidential identities is `CONFIDENTIAL_LEGAL_IDENTITY`.